# I am using the ui:composition for the header and have included it in three xhtml pages. The primefaces dialog opens only on one of them

Tags: primefaces, jsf-2.2

So I have used a ui:composition for the header to be included in all three pages. When I try to click the button to pop out the primefaces dialog, it only opens on the home page and nothing happens on the two other pages.

Here is my header:

```
<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<header id="header" class="hoc clear">
    <!-- ################################################################################################ -->
    <nav id="mainav" class="fl_left">
        <ul class="clear">
            <li class="#{funksionsBean.getIndex()}"><a href="index.xhtml">Faqja Kryesore</a></li>
            <li class="#{funksionsBean.getDestinations()}"><a href="destinations.xhtml">Destinacionet Turistike</a></li>
            <li class="#{funksionsBean.getContact()}"><a href="contact.xhtml">Na kontaktoni</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
    <div id="logo" class="fl_right">
        <h:form id="accountForm">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="background: transparent"
                rendered="#{!clientBean.logged}">
                <p:commandButton value="HYR" styleClass="login"
                    onclick="PF('logInDialog').show();" />
                <p:commandButton value="REGJISTROHU" styleClass="login" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGrid columns="3" style="background: transparent"
                rendered="#{clientBean.logged}">
                <h:outputLabel
                    value="PERSHENDETJE, #{clientBean.client.getClient_name()}"
                    styleClass="pershendetje"></h:outputLabel>
                <p:commandButton value="Llogaria" styleClass="login"
                    action="llogaria.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
                <p:commandButton value="DIL" styleClass="login"
                    action="#{clientBean.LogOut}" />
            </h:panelGrid>
            <p:dialog header="Ju lutem fusni te dhenat" widgetVar="logInDialog"
                minHeight="40">
                <h:panelGrid id="inputPanel" columns="2" cellpadding="10"
                    styleClass="logInPannel">

                    <h:outputLabel value="Email:" />
                    <h:inputText value="#{clientBean.email}" />
                    <h:outputLabel value="Password:" />
                    <h:inputSecret value="#{clientBean.password}"></h:inputSecret>

                </h:panelGrid>

                <h:commandButton action="#{clientBean.LogIn}" value="Hyr"></h:commandButton>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:form>
    </div>

</header>
```

Here is index.xhtml (the home page in witch the dialog works):

```
<html lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>ABG</title>
<link href="../resources/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" media="all"></link>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="user.css" />
</h:head>

<h:body id="top">
<div class="bgded overlay"
    style="background-image: url('../resources/images/sight-3.jpg');">
    <div class="wrapper row1">
        <ui:include src="components/header.xhtml" />
    </div>
    <section id="pageintro" class="hoc clear">
        <div>
            <h2 class="heading">Albanian Best Guide</h2>
            <p>Zgjidhni te eksploroni Shqiperine me syte tane</p>
            <p:button value="Kerko Guida" styleClass="kerko">
            </p:button>
        </div>
    </section>
</div>

<div></div>

<div class="wrapper row4 bgded overlay">
    <ui:include src="components/footer.xhtml" />
</div>

<!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
<script src="resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
<script src="resources/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
```

and here it's one of the pages that does not show the dialog 'logInDialog' when I click the button 'Hyr'. I guess the page reloads:

```
<html lang="" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<h:head>
<title>ABG | Contact</title>
<link href="../resources/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet"
    type="text/css" media="all"></link>
<h:outputStylesheet library="css" name="user.css" />
</h:head>


<h:body id="top">
<div class="bgded overlay"
    style="background-image: url('../resources/images/sight-3.jpg');">
    <div class="bgded overlay"
        style="background-image: url('../resources/images/sight-3.jpg');">
        <div class="wrapper row1">
            <ui:include src="components/header.xhtml" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- JAVASCRIPTS -->
    <script src="../resources/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/jquery.backtotop.js"></script>
    <script src="../resources/js/jquery.mobilemenu.js"></script>
</div>
```

Please help because I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Comment: I copy and pasted it into my project and replaced the bean stuff. It works in my project. Reason is possible that you have a problem with your CSS or something with your project settings. Maybe the 2nd page is not viewable without login or something

Comment: Thank you. I copy pasted the code from index.xhtml (the page that worked) and it worked in the other pages too, with the same header. I solved it but still don't understand how.